# Removing iframe url part with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to remove url part generated on every web page on my website on which I have livescore iframe module, which looks like http://mysite.com/livescore/football#inscore_ifheight_xdc_17343 ?
Real url to that page is http://mysite.com/livescore/football, but this part #inscore_ifheight_xdc_17343 is always autogenerated and added to url when open web page with livescore iframe.

If someone can generate .htaccess mod_rewrite Rewrite Rule for me I will appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not part of the URL sent to the server. So, you cannot remove it with a .htaccess rule.

The only way to prevent this, is to not create it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing me that is fragment identifier, but can you tell me efficient way to not to show it at all when client is on my web page? How to hide fragment identifier?

Comment: @MladenMijatovic The fragment identifier is in the HTML source, generated by your web server. If you don't want it, the PHP, JSP, Java ... must create the URL without it. I can't tell you more, because I don't know your web software.

Comment: I have a website created in Joomla 2.5 cms, and site consist web pages on which show sports live scores inserted as iframe, but opening web page with live score iframe (example  http://mysite.com/livescore/football) it automatically add #inscore_ifheight_xdc_17343 fragment identifier on ending of it as I mentioned in my first question. Can you tell me how to hide it or remove it so my url stays  http://mysite.com/livescore/football? Appriciate your help very much

Comment: @MladenMijatovic I'm sorry, I don't know. Depending on the module/plugin you're using, you must look through the documentation, or source code if there are no docs, and look for where the `iframe` is created. There must be some HTML fragment or PHP script, which outputs the iframe and the URL with the `#` in it.